# Did the Arizal say we must not eat even plants?

Tags: eating, vegetables

Saw this paragraph at a [Chabad site](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/858870/jewish/Judaism-and-Vegetarianism.htm) on "Judaism and vegetarianism":

> While some question the right of man to kill an animal to fill his belly, the great sixteenth-century mystic Rabbi Isaac Luria questions the right of man to consume any organism for his own self-preservation. If everything in this word was created deliberately by G‑d, why is your blood redder than the purposeful existence of a tomato? And he answers that . . . it’s not. One who eats solely for his own selfish desires has swallowed the meaningful life of a vegetable with no excuse. “It’s not fair!” cries the helpless plant.

The line "**Rabbi Isaac Luria questions the right of man to consume any organism for his own self-preservation.**" is totally unambiguous: No eating plants even to survive!  Did the Arizal really suggest that?  How are we to survive, then? By eating dead fruit falling from trees?  Is there a solid reference to the quote?

When we have succeeded in manufacturing food from individual molecules of matter, we can consider his proposal.  But until then -- pikuach nefesh!

Comment: Seems pretty clear from this quotation that the Arizal would approve of eating plants (and seemingly animals) if the eating is done for a higher purpose, not just to fulfill a man's selfish desires. I don't see why you are confused. But someone would have to track down the original source of the Ari (and read the whole chabad article) to verify

Comment: Your downvote means I should have done more before asking.  What, pray tell?  And where do you read that  "the Arizal would approve of eating plants if done for a higher purpose" in the quote?

Comment: I don't think the Arizal ever said that.

Comment: In that paragraph he just explained why pikuach nefesh wouldn't apply. By murder pikuach nefesh isn't said because who said your blood is redder than his...

Comment: I have a rule for myself: every quote from the Arizal is a misquote. That is a good rule of thumb for all quotes, but I have found it especially so by the Ari.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the article contains no citation to where the Arizal allegedly said this. However, given that the question is asked on the article's portrayal of the Arizal's view, we can answer it using just the article as well.

In the very paragraph you cite, note this key sentence:

> One who eats solely for his own selfish desires has swallowed the meaningful life of a vegetable with no excuse. “It’s not fair!” cries the helpless plant.

At face value this seems to indicate that the problem is specifically when you eat the plant for selfish reasons. So he's not saying to not eat plants; he's saying to eat them for the right reasons. This is confirmed by the very next paragraph (not cited in the question):

> On the other hand, when we eat with the intention to use the energy to further our uniquely human service of G‑d, we have lifted the food up. When a person performs a G‑dly deed—a deed which transcends his natural self—the food he eats is elevated along with him, and is reunited with its G‑dly source.

This is already enough to answer the question – if you eat plants for selfish reasons then you have "taken a life" with no excuse; if, however, you eat for the right reasons, not only is it not problematic but you're actually helping the plants.

However, the next paragraph in the article seems to retract somewhat. It says:

> But there’s a difference between animal-based and vegetation-based foods. For starters, you can’t live without bread. If you’d eat bread only when you’re ready to elevate it, you might starve to death and never get a chance to try again. So we can’t restrict bread-eating to the spiritual-minded. Moreover, when eating simple, necessary foods like bread, it is easier to maintain a purposeful perspective.

This makes it sound like you can even eat plants for selfish reasons (to prevent yourself from dying) or that staying alive is not considered a selfish reason (perhaps because, as alluded to, staying alive will give you later opportunities to do it right). It is not entirely clear, though, whether this is still what the Arizal said, or whether it is the author's own analysis of the contrast between plants and meat.

In any case, it seems pretty clear from the article that one is allowed to eat plants and need not starve to death.